# Get the last digit of a decimal value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is there any function in JavaScript that will return the unit size of the least significant digit of a decimal number?

For example:

- if the number is 1.5, return 0.1
- if the number is 0.15, return 0.01
- if the number is 0.10, return 0.01 (yeah, that's right)
- if the number is 0.100, return 0.001

And for an integer value, just return 1.

For example:

- if the number is 15, return 1
- if the number is 150, return 1
- if the number is -32, return 1

Comment: Why would you return 0.01 for 0.10? Also, keep in mind that 0.1 can't be represented in binary, so the "correct" result for that input is tricky to define.

Comment: Agree with aioobe. Not sure what you are trying to achieve, but treat it as text and count number of characters after the decimal point.

Fill with zeroes and add in number 1 at the end

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Are you aware that floating point is a little tricky? 1.10 might actually be something like `1.0999999999....` or `1.100000000001...`. Unless your input is actually text, in which case you can always just count number of chars to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: About my last comment: http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float

Comment: impossible unless you are working with strings, because Number(0.1) === Number(0.10) === Number(0.100 ) - how would any function "know what you meant" if you just pass the numeric value of one tenth?

Comment: "And for integer > 0 or < 0, just return 1"
If I'm reading this right, wouldn't that mean it would always return 1, unless the number is 0?

Answer (score 4):

Find the position of the period and compare it to the length of the string:

```js
function smallestDecimalUnit(s) {
  var pos = s.indexOf('.');
  if (pos == -1) {
    return 1;
  }
  return Math.pow(10, pos - s.length + 1);
}

function test(s) {
  document.write(s + ' &rarr; ' + smallestDecimalUnit(s) + '<br><br>');
}

test('1.5');
test('0.15');
test('0.10');
test('15');
test('150');
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```